# Tp is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

im working on a program but it keeps giving the same: name ´Tp´is not defined. here is the programm:

```
def sim(N,C,u,Tp,Cm,Temp,ac,yc,ab,aco,yco,ae):
    if u==1:
        T=Temp[0]
        ct=0
        addTemp(Temp)
        newNmol(N)
        idmax=N
        while ct<Tp:
            firstev(c)
            return cond.count()    
def addTemp(Temp):
    tT=Tp/len(Temp)
    j=0
    while j<len(Temp):
        t=tT+j*tT
        ev=event(t,"Temperature",0)
        c.addE(ev)
        j=j+1
```

Note that one of simulations arguments is Tp, please help

Comment: pleas add the correct tag. if you use python you are probably missing an import statement for whatever Pt is. Please format your code as Code - see the helps on the edit window.

Comment: You need to input 1 empty line between text and code to get if formatted correctly. If you intend to use Tp from one function paraameter inside the other function you need to put that 2. function insede the 1st - ie. ident it 4 spaces more so it "sees"  Tp. Indentation matters a lot in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you format it like this:

```
def sim(N,C,u,Tp,Cm,Temp,ac,yc,ab,aco,yco,ae):

    def addTemp(Temp):
        tT=Tp/len(Temp)
        j=0
        while j<len(Temp):
            t=tT+j*tT
            ev=event(t,"Temperature",0)
            c.addE(ev)
            j=j+1

    if u==1:
        T=Temp[0]
        ct=0
        addTemp(Temp)
        newNmol(N)
        idmax=N
        while ct<Tp:
            firstev(c)
            return cond.count()
```

`addTemp` is only visible inside `sim` 's scope and should be able to access the parameters you give to sim. If you need it elsewhere, you need to provice `Tp` to `addTemp` and leave its indentation as is.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask another one?

Comment: @BernardoAlves mark as solved and ask another question if it does not relate. If you have questions to my asnwer , ask away and Ill try to explain.

Comment: Thanks! I just have some tuple related questions, ill try to make a new post to ask them